# oVirt Hosted-Engine upgrade filed

Tags: ovirt

I'm getting problems upgrading **oVirt Hosted-Engine from 4.2.8 to 4.3.3.**

After installing [this release](http://resources.ovirt.org/pub/yum-repo/ovirt-release43.rpm) in Engine VM, I ran `yum update`, then `engine-setup` and got this error:

```
              --== DATABASE CONFIGURATION ==--

[WARNING] This release requires PostgreSQL server 10.6 but the engine database is currently hosted on PostgreSQL server 9.5.14.
[ INFO  ] Verifying PostgreSQL SELinux file context rules
[ ERROR ] Failed to execute stage 'Environment customization': could not stat file "base/13699369/1259_fsm": Permission denied

[ INFO  ] Stage: Clean up
          Log file is located at /var/log/ovirt-engine/setup/ovirt-engine-setup-20190602110956-iqr6bc.log
[ INFO  ] Generating answer file '/var/lib/ovirt-engine/setup/answers/20190602111120-setup.conf'
[ INFO  ] Stage: Pre-termination
[ INFO  ] Stage: Termination
[ ERROR ] Execution of setup failed
```

But I don't find any solution on how to solve this issue.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using [this](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_virtualization/4.3/html/upgrade_guide/upgrading_remote_databases_from_pg95_to_pg10_4-1_remote_db). 
Full lists [here](https://lists.ovirt.org/archives/list/users@ovirt.org/thread/QYAI3CP2IJMP45P4HCCX5ES7JFG3SG7U/).